# StatusBar went black after showing video with flick_video_player

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I use flick_video_player to display a video in my flutter app, but after navigating to screen with video my status bar went black. Can anyone help me to solve it?

Before navigating to this screen status bar was displayed, but when video screen builds status bar goes black and keeps it even after pop

Source code:

```
class Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('text'),
      ),
      body: Widget(),
    );
  }
}

class Widget extends StatelessWidget {
  const Widget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
      child: ListView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          Video()
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
     class Video extends StatefulWidget {
      const Video({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _VideoState createState() => _VideoState();
    }
    
    class _VideoState extends State<Video> {
      late FlickManager flickManager;
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        flickManager = FlickManager(
            videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset(
                'assets/videos/video.mp4'));
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        flickManager.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          child: Container(
            child: FlickVideoPlayer(
              preferredDeviceOrientation: [],
              flickManager: flickManager,
              flickVideoWithControls: FlickVideoWithControls(
                controls: FlickPortraitControls(),
              ),
              systemUIOverlay: [],
              flickVideoWithControlsFullscreen: FlickVideoWithControls(
                controls: FlickLandscapeControls(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue when I used it for my flutter web project.
Then I try to change the `initState` just like this

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(
        videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.asset(
            'assets/videos/video.mp4')..initialize());
  }
```

this is works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `systemUIOverlay: [],` at FlickVideoPlayer widget initialization and the system ui parts stay as they are